# How to friend someone outside of a game?

Tags: tribes-ascend

I'd like to mark someone as a friend but the only way I see to do it is on the end-game screen.

Unfortunately the person left later and now they're not on the screen so I can't friend them.

Is there a way to friend someone besides the end game screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it turns out this was a facepalm.

At the top of the list of friends, it says "Add Player" or something similar.  If you click on that button you can add any player you want.

Not sure how I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that this is on steam?

If so and you know their steam name, look for people recenlty played with (should if I remember rightly be on the friends box).